# Promote ephemeral IP to static?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have setup a compute engine VM instance with an ephemeral ip address and would like to make sure that it keeps the IP address, how can I achieve this?

Is there a way to promote the current assigned IP address to static?

I've found some info through google, but that seems to setup a new address for the server, not the current IP address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#promote_ephemeral_ip), simply go to Networking -> External IP addresses and change the type column to "Static". I've done this myself and it simply makes the same IP address static.

NOTE: You will be charged for the IP addresses that you do not allocate to instances.

Answer (score 0):

GCloud command to change ephemeral to static:

```
gcloud compute addresses create ADDRESS_NAME \
  --addresses IP \
  --region REGION_NAME
```

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip